# cant override default table heading color of page-> sort using css

Tags: css

In cakephp I cant cant get rid of the default horrible table heading blue color with a css tag. The below th css code has no effect on the color but it does so on the font size. The docs in pagination for page-sort doesnt say anything. How can I get hold of a css tag that changes the whole table heading row?

```
.style1 th {
    background-color:white;

    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:black;

}
..
<table class="style1" >
    <tr>
           <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('first_name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('last_name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('guardian_first_name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('guardian_last_name'); ?></th>


    </tr>
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html

Comment: The docs say nothing because this has *nothing* to do with (Cake) php.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this and remove an extra `tr`

```
table.style1 tr th {
    background-color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:black;

}
```

Comment: Neither of the above options worked. The color is still blue on the th tags and I dont have an extra tr tag as it will an error I did here. The problem is a little harder to fix it appears

Comment: I found the element in boot_strap.css , so I comment the color out BUT it still appears blue after a refresh and reboot of the pc.   I cant get rid of this horrible blue color from the header tag.   body{
    margin:0;font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    //font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#333333;background-color:#ffffff;
}

Answer (score 0):

This will be to do with CSS Precedence: http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Basically something with a higher importance is applying its own styles instead of yours, so for example:

`th { color: blue;}` would be over-written by `table th {color: red; }` which would be over-written by `div table th { color: black; }` and so on.

Use Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature (or similar) to find out the rule applied to this element so that you can make your own more specific.

Alternatively you could use the `!important` css rule which will always apply that rule, regardless of precedence, but this isn't always the best option usually and is just a quick fix: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

You would apply `!important` to your css like so:

```
.style1 th {
    background-color:white !important;
    font-size:20px !important;
    font-family:Arial !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    color:black !important;

}
```

P.S you also have a rogue `<tr>` tag in your HMTL